# Access violation while passing pinned int pointer in C#

Tags: c#, interop, unmanaged, access-violation

I have a code(dll) in C++ that I need to call from my C# code. When I use a pinned pointer it throws an access violation exception. I am not sure what I am missing.

The following is the class which creates the pinned pointer.

```
public class PinnedCmdCtrlBlock
    {
        GCHandle handle;
        CmdCtrlBlock cmd; 

 //This is the structure that needs to be pinned
        public IntPtr CmdCtrlBlockPtr;

        public PinnedCmdCtrlBlock()
        {
            cmd = new CmdCtrlBlock();
            handle = GCHandle.Alloc(cmd,GCHandleType.Pinned);

           CmdCtrlBlockPtr = handle.AddrOfPinnedObject();                
        }

        ~PinnedCmdCtrlBlock()
        {
            handle.Free();
        }
    };
```

The following is the code that calls the actual C++ unmanaged code

```
PinnedCmdCtrlBlock pinPtr = new PinnedCmdCtrlBlock();
int addr = PinPtr.CmdCtrlBlockPtr.ToInt32();
HartConnection.HartCmd(0, ref  addr);
```

Comment: I really don't understand your code. You are instantiating pinPtr to a class (it is not a pointer), and then you assign it to an integer.  Why did you instantiate it?  You may want to do a Google search on C# and marshaling.

Comment: It is fundamentally unsafe, the object can be finalized while the C++ code is running.  GC.KeepAlive() on the cmd object is required.  This is why SafeHandle exists.  However, this probably crashes quicker than that.  The *ref* is almost certainly wrong.  That creates a cmd**, not a cmd*.  That's not otherwise obvious without seeing the C++ code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I copied the wrong variable while typing the code above. I created a class PinnedCmdCtrlBlock and the constructor and assigns the handle(Alloc value) to a member. I am not sure how to pass the IntPtr as a long* (which the C++ function needs). I tried the Unsafe option and tried to type cast it like so `unsafe { long * ptr = (long*) handle.AddrOfPinnedObject().

Comment: Hi Hans, Unfortunately I dont have the C++ code I just have the API to call the C++ library. the C# compiler refuses to compile without a ref as mentioned in the error. The C++ signature for this method is HartCmd(int, ref int);